# My downvotes are going against me

Tags: bug, answers, downvotes

I downvoted a couple of answers and it downvoted me and affected my tally.

Is this how it's supposed to work?

[How to assign a PHP variable to a JavaScript variable inside JavaScript code? The whole file is PHP though](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28700137/how-to-assign-a-php-variable-to-a-javascript-variable-inside-javascript-code-th/28700197#28700197)

Comment: You lose 1 rep for each downvote on answers. Question downvotes are free.

Comment: Oh OK. So when I vote someone else down, I love rep points? That's interesting.

Comment: Should I just delete this question?

Comment: You lose reputation points unless that post is deleted. Then they are refunded. This is basically a literal "I'm willing to place my reputation on the line to say that this thing is bad."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you mean that you downvoted answers and your reputation dropped than that's correct.

Downvotes on answers cost the downvoter 1 rep.